# Is it possible to implement a Mega Drop Down Menu using pure CSS?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I would like to implement a Mega Drop Down Menu for my Navigation Menu using pure CSS i.e. NO Javascript/JQuery. When the user hovers on a navigation item, I'd like to display a mega drown menu which stays active if the user is within the bounds of the menu. If the user moves away or hovers over a different menu, it should then display the relevant menu.

[image: Navigation menu with mega drop down]

The below image depicts exactly what I'm looking for. 
`GAMES AND TOYS` is the first `nav-item` which on hover should display the mega drop down menu (the overlay with a `#ff1300` border). The yellow boxes represent the different nested divs that I'd like to show within a container div.

**Note: I've already tried putting the nav-item and a drop-down within a single div and using

```
.nav-item:hover .dropdownpanel {
    display: block 
/*    This is set to display: none to be hidden and then shown on hover */
}
```

Is there a way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: It's possible but I would seriously consider using JS for some additional UI/UX magic. http://bjk5.com/post/44698559168/breaking-down-amazons-mega-dropdown

Comment: Actually, I'm using this for a scenario (eBay) where JS is restricted. Therefore, I was looking to do this using CSS.

Comment: Actually, I'm just looking to display a really big overlay (div) when the nav items are hovered without breaking the layout. can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.

**An example using list based mega menu.**

```css
/* Outline declarations are for visual demonstration purposes only */

html, body {padding:0;margin:0 auto;}
nav {width:100%;padding:0;margin:0; position:relative;}
nav ul {width:100%;list-style:none;padding:0;margin:0;display:table;}
nav ul li {display:table-cell; line-height:2em;padding:0 1em;outline:1px solid green;}
nav ul li div {outline:solid 1px yellow;}
nav ul li > ul {width:100%;position:absolute;left:0;right:0;display:none;outline:solid 1px red;}
nav ul ul > li {display:table-cell;float:none;}
nav > ul > li:hover {background:cyan;}
nav li:hover > ul {display:table;}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Has Mega Menu
            <ul>
                <li><div>Stuff <br />Stuff <br />Stuff <br />Stuff <br />Stuff <br />Stuff <br />Stuff <br />Stuff <br />Stuff <br /></div></li>
                <li><div>Stuff <br />Stuff <br /></div></li>
                <li><div>Stuff <br />Stuff <br />Stuff <br />Stuff <br />Stuff <br />Stuff <br /></div></li>
                <li><div>Stuff <br />Stuff <br />Stuff <br />Stuff <br /></div></li>
             </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Menu Item</li>
        <li>Also has Mega Menu
            <ul>
                <li><div>Other Stuff <br />Other Stuff <br />Other Stuff <br />Other Stuff <br />Other Stuff <br />Other Stuff <br />Other Stuff <br />Other Stuff <br />Other Stuff <br /></div></li>
                <li><div>Other Stuff <br />Other Stuff <br /></div></li>
                <li><div>Other Stuff <br />Other Stuff <br />Other Stuff <br />Other Stuff <br />Other Stuff <br />Other Stuff <br /></div></li>
                <li><div>Other Stuff <br />Other Stuff <br />Other Stuff <br />Other Stuff <br /></div></li>
             </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Menu Item</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**EDIT: Added the following example using Div based mega menu.**

```css
/* Outline declarations are for visual demonstration purposes only */

html, body {padding:0;margin:0 auto;}
nav {width:100%;padding:0;margin:0; position:relative;}
nav ul {width:100%;list-style:none;padding:0;margin:0;display:table;}
nav ul li {display:table-cell; line-height:2em;padding:0 1em;outline:1px solid green;}
nav ul li div {outline:solid 1px yellow;}
nav ul li > div {width:100%;position:absolute;left:0;right:0;display:none;outline:solid 1px red;}
nav ul li > div > div {display:table-cell;padding:1em;}
nav > ul > li:hover {background:cyan;}
nav > ul > li:hover > div {display:table;}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Has Mega Menu
            <div>
                <div>Stuff <br />Stuff <br />Stuff <br />Stuff <br />Stuff <br />Stuff <br />Stuff <br />Stuff <br />Stuff <br /></div>
                <div>Stuff <br />Stuff <br /></div>
                <div>Stuff <br />Stuff <br />Stuff <br />Stuff <br />Stuff <br />Stuff <br /></div>
                <div>Stuff <br />Stuff <br />Stuff <br />Stuff <br /></div>
             </div>
        </li>
        <li>Menu Item</li>
        <li>Also has Mega Menu
            <div>
                <div>Other Stuff <br />Other Stuff <br />Other Stuff <br />Other Stuff <br />Other Stuff <br />Other Stuff <br />Other Stuff <br />Other Stuff <br />Other Stuff <br /></div>
                <div>Other Stuff <br />Other Stuff <br /></div>
                <div>Other Stuff <br />Other Stuff <br />Other Stuff <br />Other Stuff <br />Other Stuff <br />Other Stuff <br /></div>
                <div>Other Stuff <br />Other Stuff <br />Other Stuff <br />Other Stuff <br /></div>
             </div>
        </li>
        <li>Menu Item</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I gave it a quick try in chrome dev tools. It seems to work as I'd like it to :) I'll get back to you as soon as I've tried it. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score -1):

Yes That can be done by pure CSS. I found this link http://technodator.com/2015/07/20-cool-css-for-megamenu.html they have 20 css mega menu script but most of them are for sale round a few dollar.